# An excel function like WEBSERVICE but works on https

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to pull data from an api
There is a simple https web address that if you type it in google url you get a json back
However it seems that the =WEBSERVICE function in excel does not work on https sites only http ie webservice doesnt like any sort of authentication

Ive searched but cant seem to solve this without having to resort to VBA

Is there a way around this? Another function im not aware of?

An example of a url that doesnt work for me is

```
https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker
```

This produces a #VALUE result in excel

```
=WEBSERVICE("https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker")
```

Comment: It works fine with HTTPS, E.g. `=WEBSERVICE("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")` so the problem is elsewhere.  What actually happens when you try? Whats an example failing URL?

Comment: I have added an example url to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL returns ~38K of data but according to the [`WEBSERVICE()` docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/webservice-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4):

> If arguments result in a string that is not valid **or that contains more than the allowable cell limit of 32767 characters**, WEBSERVICE returns the #VALUE! error value.

Given that the amount of data exceeds what you can stuff into a cell your going to need a different approach, [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-a-json-file-f65207ab-d957-4bf0-bec3-a08bb53cd4c0) is one alternative.